# Delete Windows software development kit

Tags: windows, macos, parallels

Hi I am using Macbook Pro, and I use windows10 by parallels

I use windows10 only for programming(visual studio), and I want to delete

everything unnecessary.

when I delete file, I found windows SDK.

I don't want windows10 updates, then can I delete it??

And, how can i improve speed in using windows, parallels??

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, then I'm pretty sure you need the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to delete *everything* but you should allow parallels to use more of your Mac's RAM and CPU. That will help with the speed of Windows.

Comment: oh! I see! Thanks!

Comment: If I helped answer your question, could you please mark it as correct? Thank you!